# When drawing with a tablet in Inkscape the path is very rough and distorted. How can I fix that?

Tags: inkscape, drawing-tablet

When I draw with my drawing tablet in Inkscape the trail is very jagged. I feel the resolution of the tablet isn't fully used. How can I set up my tablet to work with Inkscape correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Edit → Input Devices…*
Select your tablet.
Press Save.